# Wondering how to connect the lines shown in the top left image of opencv webcam

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, kivy

I am struggling (due to my lack of experience with opencv) to find the whole rectangle drawn in the test image at the bottom. Currently the code, as seen in the image below, is only finding a very small amount of the rectangle. I have tried changing the min and max line lengths in an attempt to fix the issue but that did not work. The final application of this code will be to determine overall length of a side of a rectangular prism so this issue is not good for me to leave as is. (Code and test image are below)

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdjdy.png)

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture

import cv2
import numpy as np

class CamApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.img0 = Image()
        self.img1 = Image()
        self.img2 = Image()
        self.img3 = Image()

        layout = GridLayout(cols = 4, rows = 3)

        # I get tired easy with repitition if you can tell.
        layout.add_widget(self.img0)
        layout.add_widget(self.img1)
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="Place Holder"))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="Place Holder"))
        layout.add_widget(self.img2)
        layout.add_widget(self.img3)
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="Place Holder"))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="Place Holder"))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="Place Holder"))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="Place Holder"))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="Place Holder"))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="Place Holder"))

        #opencv2 stuffs
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/33.0)
        return layout

    def update(self, dt):
        # display image from cam in opencv window
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        # Flip Image and set up first frame
        buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, -1)

        # Convert main frame to Grayscale
        buf3 = cv2.cvtColor(buf1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Take Grayscale and add an adaptiveThreshold
        buf5 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(buf3,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

        # Edge detection and line detection
        buf7 = cv2.Canny(buf3,80,240,3)
        buf8 = cv2.HoughLinesP(buf7, 1, np.pi/180, 60, np.array([]), 50, 5)
        if np.any(buf8) == True:
            print(buf8)

            for line in buf8:
                for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
                    cv2.line(buf1, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 5)
                    distance_pixels = np.sqrt(np.square(x2 - x1) + np.square(y2 - y1))
                    print(distance_pixels)

        # Necessary to display all the transformations and other bullshit
        buf0 = buf1.tostring()
        buf2 = buf3.tostring()
        buf4 = buf5.tostring()
        buf6 = buf7.tostring()

        # The next 9 lines are kivy bullshit to get the images on the screen.
        texture0 = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture1 = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='luminance')
        texture2 = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='luminance')
        texture3 = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='luminance')

        texture0.blit_buffer(buf0, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        texture1.blit_buffer(buf2, colorfmt='luminance', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        texture2.blit_buffer(buf4, colorfmt='luminance', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        texture3.blit_buffer(buf6, colorfmt='luminance', bufferfmt='ubyte')

        # display image from the texture
        self.img0.texture = texture0
        self.img1.texture = texture1
        self.img2.texture = texture2
        self.img3.texture = texture3

# Here's the running shit.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Test Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaAfT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

After the thresholding, instead of using HoughLinesP for detection, use findContours() function to find the contours.

[See this for information on contours.](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html)

Note that find contours in your image using RETR_EXTERNAL flag. After finding the contours, draw these contours in a new black image with thickness=-1. now apply erosion and dilation on this image to remove noise and then again find the contour in the same way. This will give you the contour of the required rectangle.

If still more than one contour is found, take the contour with maximum area. (As it is obvious that this rectangle will be of maximum area). For information about contour area, [refer to this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#contour-area).

[Same approach is used to solve this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679083/how-do-i-separate-overlapping-cards-from-each-other-using-python-opencv/62827973#62827973). Refer this to get more understanding of my approach.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I figured it out. I was using the wrong function. So instead of using the houghlines function I was supposed to use the draw contours function. Sorry for any trouble.

Comment: Yes, see my answer below for more detailed solution.